# WPF Button Effect Properties - How to Change Visual Effects

Tags: wpf, controls

I'm fairly new to WPF and could use some pointers.

I'm writing an application using VMMV.  I have a series of 'Action' buttons (Refresh, Edit, Add, Save, Remove, etc.) contained in a Expander and I'm trying to either have a DropShadowEffect or a BlurEffect to display if the button is usable to the end user.
[How I Expected The Buttons To Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vir8.png)

I have the Style bound to the 'Tag' property of the button.
The 'Tag' property of the button is bound to a property in the VM and is a boolean value.

My issue is, using the 'Tag' property in the Style, I get neither the DropShadowEffect nor the BlurEffect at runtime.
[Buttons with Style as 'Tag' - No Drop Shadow, No Blur effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oQLZ.png)

If I replace the 'Tag' with the Button's 'IsEnabled' property in both the Button and the Style sections of code, the DropShadowEffects work as expected, but the Blur does not.  Instead of blurring the button
'as is', it seems to remove the button entirely, but leaves the Text Content of the button on screen and just shows as white space...this is the same effect as if I were to not use any style at all, with the IsEnabled property of the Button set to false.
[Buttons with Style as 'IsEnabled' - Get DropShadow, but Blur not looking right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkfPx.png)

What am I doing wrong with the Tag property?

I've looked through several posts here and elsewhere, and nothing I've seen/read resolves the issue.

I have a Style under my Expander Resources for my buttons:

```
<Expander.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButton">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DropShadowEffect />
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <BlurEffect Radius="3"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Expander.Resources>
```

The Code for my Buttons look like this:

```
                         <Button x:Name="SaveChangesButtonClicked"
                               Tag="{Binding IsARSaveChangesButtonEnabled}"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="3"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Height="50"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"                
                                Width="134" 
                                Margin="9,4,2,3"
                                Background="Gray"
                                FontSize="11"
                                Foreground="White"
                                Content="Save Changes"
                                Style="{StaticResource MyButton}">
                        </Button>
```

Comment: Icommand has canexecute which is used to drive whether the command can be used. Bind to a command and use isenabled rather than tag.

Comment: Not sure I follow completely.  Button is already bound to a command (SaveChangesButtonClicked) using x:Name.  It will change the value of IsARSaveChangesButtonEnabled (among other things).  Replacing Tag with IsEnabled won't give me the desired results.